# How to install python package from git repo that has git-lfs content with pip?

Tags: python, git, pip, git-lfs

I have migrated large files in my git repository to git-lfs. The repository contains the source code of a custom python library. I was able to install it with pip:

```
pip install git+https://gitserver.com/myrepo.git@branch
```

Currently (after migration), large files that are stored at lfs, obviously, are out of the installation (there are only links). I have installed git-lfs package from PyPI in the environment but it does not help.
Is there any way to tell pip to fetch git-lfs files while cloning the repo?

Comment: clone the package source and then run `pip install -e .` in package folder.

Comment: Report the problem at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your per-user or system configuration settings properly set, then Git will automatically invoke Git LFS when cloning a repository that uses Git LFS.

The easiest way to do this is to run `git lfs install --skip-repo`, which will modify your `.gitconfig` to contain the proper entries. You can verify that your configuration is correct by running `git lfs env` and making sure that the last three `git config` options printed are non-empty.

Once that's set up, any time you clone a new repository using Git LFS, the LFS files will be automatically fetched and filled in. If you have an existing repository, you can use `git lfs checkout` to check out the files manually.

Answer (score 5):

I came accross the same issue where I have several internal python packages containing LFS files. Each of them having their own `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` files where one is based on pip and doesn't handle well the `git lfs` and the other is based on `setuptools`...

My `requirements.txt` looks like:

```
pip_package1==0.1
pip_package2==0.2
pip_package3==0.3
git+ssh://git@{url}:{port}/{repo}.git@{branch}
```

In the `setup.py` a solution is to catch any `git+ssh` to not let them into the `setup` function but forcing their installation through pip:

```
def install_requires():
    reqdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(os.path.join(reqdir, 'requirements.txt'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
        all_packages = f.readlines()
        packages = [
            package
            for package in all_packages
            if 'git+ssh' not in package
        ]
        manual_pip_packages = [
            package
            for package in all_packages
            if 'git+ssh' in package
        ]
        for package in manual_pip_packages:
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
    return packages
```

Then the `pip` / `git lfs` compatibility. What I understood is a `pip install` on a git repo will simply `git clone` and then `python setup.py [something]` so I added in each `setup.py` within a package containing lfs files a `git pull` supposing the concerning `setup.py` is inside a git repository.

```
def pull_first():
    """This script is in a git directory that can be pulled."""
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    gitdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.chdir(gitdir)
    g = git.cmd.Git(gitdir)
    try:
        g.execute(['git', 'lfs', 'pull'])
    except git.exc.GitCommandError:
        raise RuntimeError("Make sure git-lfs is installed!")
    os.chdir(cwd)
```

That way I have a `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import os
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    import git
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gitpython'])
    import git


def install_requires():
    ...


def pull_first():
    ...


pull_first()

setup(name=...,
      version=...,
      description=...,
      long_description=...,
      url=...,
      author=...,
      license=...,
      packages=find_packages(),
      python_requires=">=3.0",
      install_requires=install_requires())
```