# How to publish a Python package located in a git repository that contains git lfs files?

Tags: python, git, git-lfs

I am trying to make a Python package I have created can be `pip install`ed.

The answer [How to install python package from git repo that has git-lfs content with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393372/how-to-install-python-package-from-git-repo-that-has-git-lfs-content-with-pip) to my question is simply not working.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

### Download and Install from Github

If you want to "Download ZIP" file from git and install by running `pip install path/to/package.zip`, then you will need to modify your settings on Github. These files are store in an `Archives/` folder on Github. Please see https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-git-lfs-objects-in-archives-of-your-repository. You need to go to Settings -> Archives and then check the box that says **Include Git LFS objects in archives**.

After doing that, I made a *Release*. I then downloaded that release, and the git-lfs files were downloaded in full rather than the ones containing pointer information.

### Git Clone or Make Installable on PyPI

PyPI does a `git clone` on a repository. Therefore, you will need to actually `git pull` the repository from inside of your `setup.py` file. This part of the question is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932741/11637415, and I provide a slightly simplified presentation. You will need to `import git` and then call the following `pull_first()` function in your `setup.py` file.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    import git
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gitpython'])
    import git


def pull_first():
    """This script is in a git directory that can be pulled."""
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    gitdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.chdir(gitdir)
    g = git.cmd.Git(gitdir)
    try:
        g.execute(['git', 'lfs', 'pull'])
    except git.exc.GitCommandError:
        raise RuntimeError("Make sure git-lfs is installed!")
    os.chdir(cwd)


pull_first()

setup(name=...,
      version=...,
      description=...,
      long_description=...,
      url=...,
      author=...,
      license=...,
      packages=find_packages(),
      python_requires=">=3.0",
      install_requires=install_requires())
```