# Install package from git including git-lfs files with poetry

Tags: git, python-poetry, git-lfs

I have a package in a private repository that I am referencing in another python project. The repo I am using as a dependency has some ML model files stored in GitLFS Everything in both repositories have been setup using Poetry.  My top level repository has the following dependency

```
my_package = {git = "ssh://git@github.com/my_org/my_package", branch = "develop"}
```

When I do a poetry install the package is pulled and I see it in my .venv directory, but the git-lfs files are all just pointers.

So far I have tried the things referenced in this question
[How to install python package from git repo that has git-lfs content with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393372/how-to-install-python-package-from-git-repo-that-has-git-lfs-content-with-pip)

I have also switched to the system git client using the following command

```
poetry config experimental.system-git-client true
```

Nothing seems to do a full clone with git-lfs.  Is there something I am missing here?